# Django is "unable to open database file"

Tags: database, django, sqlite, django-models, django-admin

after running "python manage.py syncdb" i gett an error saying "unable to open database file".

here is the important part from my settings.py:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'sqlite3'    # 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
DATABASE_NAME = 'apps.db'      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
DATABASE_USER = ''             # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''         # Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_HOST = ''             # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
DATABASE_PORT = ''             # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
```

and here are the permissions for "apps.db":

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 33792 19. Jul 10:51 apps.db
```

My django server is called from apache... i don't know if it has to do with the permissions but changing the owner of apps.db to "www-data" did not work either

[edit]

to ensure www-data can access all of this i did the following:

did the following:

```
chown -R www-data apps
rm apps.db
su www-data
python manage.py syncdb
```

but it still does not work :(

Comment: Make sure that www-data can walk the entire path to your db, and not just read/write the db file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved the error by changing the DATABASE_NAME to an absolute path: `/var/www/apps/apps.db`.

On a windows machine, backslash should be escaped like: `C:\\path\\to\\database\\database_name.db`.

Comment: What if I'm trying to access the database via network and the path starts with "\\MyMachine\..." which translates to "\\\\MyMachine\\..." . Then I can't open the connection, I get "unable to open database file". Even if the database is on my machine, I'm just trying to access it in a different way.

Answer (score 50):

[Solution from NewbieMistakes](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3)

> Make sure Apache can also write to the parent directory of the
>   database. SQLite needs to be able to write to this directory.
>
> Make sure each folder of your database file's full path does not start
>   with number, eg. /www/4myweb/db (observed on Windows 2000).
>
> If DATABASE_NAME is set to something like
>   '/Users/yourname/Sites/mydjangoproject/db/db', make sure you've
>   created the 'db' directory first.
>
> Make sure your /tmp directory is world-writable (an unlikely cause as
>   other thing on your system will also not work). ls /tmp -ald should
>   produce drwxrwxrwt ....
>
> Make sure the path to the database specified in settings.py is a full
>   path.

Comment: The parent directory permission was non-obvious (to me); thanks.

Comment: There's an FAQ entry [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3) as well.

Comment: So should I really fire `chmod 777` on database-containing directory?

Answer (score 6):

DATABASE_NAME is deprecated. You must use the currently supported format.
i.e.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': 'C:/ispdb.sqlite',
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',
    'PORT': ''

}
```

And also see other settings which are deprecated from the django website.:))

Answer (score 4):

For my linux system, I had to give process owner write permission to both the **db.sqlite3** and the **directory** that contained it! You could just setfacl instead! example: (https://serverfault.com/questions/484818/best-way-to-set-up-permissions-with-nginx-php-fpm-on-shared-hosting).

(py2.7)[me@server django-project-container]$ ls -la djangoproject/

```
drwxrwxr-x. 6 root nginx  4096 Jun 14 01:05 .
drwxr-xr-x. 6 root root  4096 Jun 13 23:47 ..
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root nginx 49152 Jun 14 01:05 db.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I answered it on this question. http://goo.gl/KAuXz

I faced exactly same issue. Here is my setting which worked.

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
'NAME': '/home/neo/django/db/data.sqlite3'
```

Other setting in case of sqlite3 will be same/default.

Answer (score 1):

Just rename the database file with .sqlite3 extension, that works with me.

Answer (score 0):

To change the permission of parent directory, you can use below set of commands:

check apache process for apache v2:

```
ps -ef | grep apache | grep -v grep
```

the user/group is www-data

```
chgrp www-data /path/to/mydir
chmod g+w /path/to/mydir
```

Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/58725/how-do-we-know-that-a-directory-is-apache-writable

Answer (score 0):

Check if the folder is in the Windows Ransomware Protection. Remove it if it is.